# Text Area interfering with Ajax Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am just trying to clear the text area with an id of "discussion" it clears the textbox but it does not load the data from the server with the ajax statement. When I remove the line that clears that text area it loads all the data in fine but just adds to the current data.

Here is my code:

```
function LoadRoomMessages(id)
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "Get",
        url: "@Url.Action("GetMessages", "Home")",
        data: { roomId: id },
        success: function (data)
        {
              // Here is the line that causes issues.
              $('#discussion').val('');
              json = data;
              var obj = JSON.parse(json);
              for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
              {
                  $('#discussion').append(htmlEncode(obj[i].Author) + " : " + htmlEncode(obj[i].Message) + "\r\n");
              }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I really didn't understand the question exactly ? Is `$('#discussion')` `textarea` ? What is the issue with `$('#discussion').val('');` ?

Comment: Yes, the discussion area is the textarea. The issue is that when i have the line $('#discussion').val(''); it clears the text area but never populates the textarea after

Comment: the .empty() worked. Thank you so much. Please post that as your answer so i can give you credit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also try (as you asked to answer it)

```
$('#discussion').empty();
```

Comment: I need to wait 5 minutes